# Is there a way to calculate ratio between a crosstab dataframe with another dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

**Summary** - the end goal is to calculate the percentage based on the output from a crosstab function in Pandas with another dataframe at a shared index.

**What I've tried** - tried to split the original crosstab dataframe as numerator and `div` another dataframe, but it doesn't seem to work that way because the result was all `nan`

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Vntg": ["2020-01","2020-02","2020-03"],"Funded":[1000,2000,4000]}) # This is the df we want to use as denominator
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Vntg": ["2020-01","2020-01","2020-01","2020-02","2020-02","2020-03"],
                    "Funded":[1000,1000,1000,2000,2000,4000],
                    "Payment":[10,20,20,30,15,30],
                    "Timing":[0,1,2,0,1,0]})
ct_df = pd.crosstab(df2["Vntg"], df2["Timing"], values=df2["Payment"], aggfunc="sum", margins=False)
ct_df = ct_df.cumsum(axis=1) # This is the crosstab df we want to use as numerator on a cumulative basis
```

Starting from the `cumsum` to accumulate the payments, is there a way to convert/replace the dollar value by funded amount in `df1` as a percentage? Thanks in advance and appreciate all the help.

I've also looked at the thread below and it doesn't seem to solve my issue:
[Customized normalization of pd.crosstab()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69522291/customized-normalization-of-pd-crosstab)

**Edit:**

So I think some folks are confused about the ask. To clarify, the final result would be taking 10 from `df2` at timing 0 and divided by funded amount, which is 1000 from `df1` for vintage 2020-01. For the subsequent timing at 1, it would just be (10+30) from `df2` and divided the same funded amount from `df1` for the same vintage because it doesn't change in nature. The result would be populated by the same logic for other vintages.

Comment: Hi limasuma - I'm a little confused about the meaning of the various columns in both dataframes, but especially "payment" and "timing" in `df2`. When you say "convert/replace the dollar value by funded amount in `df1` as a percentage", would it simply be appropriate to divide the column by its total?

Comment: @DaveB yes, that was my initial take by simply divide the funded column in `df1` but it doesn't seem to solve my issue because it returns all `nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the expected output in the form of dataframe, it will be easier for everyone:

```
>>> ct_df.cumsum(axis=1).div(df1.set_index('Vntg')['Funded'], axis=0).mul(100)
Timing      0     1    2
Vntg                    
2020-01  1.00  3.00  5.0
2020-02  1.50  2.25  NaN
2020-03  0.75   NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach below doesn't use `crosstab`, but should give the same answer (IIUC):

```py
(
    df2.sort_values(["Vntg", "Timing"])
    .assign(cum_paymt=lambda df: df.groupby("Timing")["Payment"].transform("cumsum"))
    .assign(cum_share=lambda df: df["cum_paymt"] / df["Funded"])
    .pivot(index="Vntg", columns="Timing", values="cum_share")
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can see how it works and its very close. To clarify, the end result would be at timing 0, taking 10/1000 funded amount for vintage 2020-01, and (10+30)/1000 for timing 1. That funded amount doesn't change and it has to be coming from df1 because funded in df2 inflates due to duplicates.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand correctly. The "funded" column is not affect by the duplicates, right?

Comment: The "funded" column in `df2` does because it would be simply matched from `df1` based on vintage. For example, funded for 2020-01 is 1000 instead of 3000 if we were looking at `df2`. I also made some edits and let me know if that makes sense.